NoCredentialException in android code when trying to implement Google SSO using credential manager
I've been spending the past 10h trying to add a SIMPLE SSO BUTTON. All I want is to be able to sign my users into my app using Google credentials. To this effect, I've had a look at the following links (non-exhaustive list):

https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/legacy-sign-in
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

It should come as no surprise that they all offer wildly differing information, none of it either useful or resulting in even distantly working code.
The relevant code I am trying to get to work is as follows:
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE)
    private fun signInNow(context: Context){
        Log.d("login", "new request")
        val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
            .setServerClientId(<MY_CLIENT_ID>)
            .build()

        val googleSignRequest: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
            .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
            .build()

        Log.d("login", googleSignRequest.toString())

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            try {
                val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                    request = googleSignRequest,
                    context = context,
                )
                handleSignIn(result)
            } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Something went wrong:", e)
            }
        }
    }

My app's package name is com.company.myapp_android. I have it set up that the assetlinks.json file is served through static.company.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json. I double checked that the file is correctly served with the proper content-type header. I got the SHA-256 signature in the file directly from my keystore.
I've made sure the user signed in on my device is authorized in the console as a test user (since my app is not published yet). Anytime I try to sign up however (clicking a button that triggers the function above), I get the following error:
androidx.credentials.exceptions.NoCredentialException: No credentials available.
I also tried to use the GetSignInWithGoogleOption but this results in a [16] Account reauth failed. error.
Any help would be highly appreciated at this point.


Credential manager is showing strange behavior now a days, some time it is providing null email and null user name, which forced me to rollback to legacy signup method of google.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
